# True or False f is Onto iff f(X) = Y

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $f:X\to Y$, then $f$ is onto iff $f(X)=Y$. Where $X$ and $Y$ are sets.

I know for this to be true it has to be true in both directions meaning:

(i) If $f$ is onto, then $f(X) = Y$.

(ii) If $f(X) = Y$, then $f$ is onto.

If believe (i) is true, but I think (ii) could be one-to-one, onto, or neither.
Just looking for some verification on this. Making sure I interpreted the question correctly.

Comment: What is your definition of onto? (i) and (ii) are almost true by definition. But $f(X)=Y$ says nothing about whether $f$ is one-to-one or not.

Comment: "$f(X)=Y$" is just a symbolic way of saying "$f$ is onto". The meaning behind these two sentences is exactly the same. I'm not sure what you want to prove here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, both (i) and (ii) are true essentially by definition. A function $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is onto if $\forall y\in Y$ $\exists x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. In other words, the image of $f$ is the entire set $Y$. Because this is a definition, indeed both (i) and (ii) follow from it. On the other hand, the definition of one-to-one does not have anything to do with your stated conditions in the question: a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is one-to-one if $\forall a,b\in X$, $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $a=b$, which is not suggested by either (i) nor (ii).